# How to animate a matrix changing the sprites one by one?

Tags: swift, animation, matrix, sprite-kit, action

I´m making a little game were I have a matrix compose for SKSpriteNode and numbers, when the game its over I´m trying to make an animation were I go over the matrix changing only the sprite one by one following the order of the numbers. Look the 
[Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0FLM.png) (The squares are in a Sknode and the number in other Sknode)

The Idea is change the sprite to other color and wait 2 sec after change the next but I can´t do it. I don't know how to change the sprite one by one. I make this function "RecoverMatrix()", this change the sprites but all at once, it is as if not take the wait, he change all the sprites and before wait the 2 sec.

```
func RecoverMatrix() {                         

    var cont = 1
    TileLayer.removeAllChildren()
    numLayer.removeAllChildren()
    let imageEnd = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "rectangle-play"))
    let waiting = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)

    var scene: [SKAction] = []
    var tiles: [SKSpriteNode] = []

    while cont <= 16 {

        for var column = 0; column < 4; column++ {
            for var row = 0; row < 4; row++ {

                if matrix[column][row].number  == cont {

                    let label = SKLabelNode()
                    label.text = "\(matrix[column][row])"
                    label.fontSize = TileHeight - 10
                    label.position = pointForBoard(column, row: row)
                    label.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

                    let tile = SKSpriteNode()
                    tile.size = CGSize(width: TileWidth - 3, height: TileHeight - 3)
                    tile.position = pointForBoard(column, row: row, _a: 0)
                    TileLayer.addChild(tile)
                    numLayer.addChild(label)

                    tiles.append(tile)

                    scene.append(SKAction.sequence([imageEnd, waiting]))

                    tile.runAction(imageEnd)
                    runAction(waiting)
                    didEvaluateActions()
                }
            }
        }
        cont++
    }

    for tile in tiles {
        tile.runAction(SKAction.sequence(scene))
        self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(1))
    }
}
```

So, I need help, I don't find the way to make this animation. I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: It is certainly doable if I understand you well... Haven't looked closely in your code, but I will assume that you already have an array of sprites with preserved order. What you have to do is to loop through all of them (like you do,inside of a for loop) and run an action sequence on each tile (sprite) you want to change. The action sequence should have basically two parts. First part will be `SKAction.waitForDuration()` and that should change for each tile. Second part is actual color change or whatever you plan. So, just calculate wait action appropriately, and you will get effect you want.

Comment: So basically you just have to increase wait duration for each node. Also, you should probably run this sequence on each node separately, not on the scene. And what is that `didEvaluateActions()` call inside your while loop ? That looks shady :) You should not call that method [directly](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didEvaluateActions)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can run an action on every node at the same time (using a loop to loop through all the tiles):

```
class GameScene: BaseScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
  var blocks: [[SKSpriteNode]] = []

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    makeBoard(4, height: 4)

    colorize()
  }

  func makeBoard(width:Int, height:Int) {
    let distance:CGFloat = 50.0

    var blockID = 1

    //make a width x height matrix of SKSpriteNodes
    for j in 0..<height {
      var row = [SKSpriteNode]()

      for i in 0..<width {
        let node = SKSpriteNode(color: .purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        node.name = "\(blockID++)"

        if let nodeName = node.name {node.addChild(getLabel(withText: nodeName))}
        else {
          //handle error
        }

        node.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX + CGFloat(i) * distance,
          y: frame.midY - CGFloat(j) * distance )

        row.append(node)

        addChild(node)
      }

      blocks.append(row)
    }
  }

  func colorize() {
    let colorize = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.blackColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0, duration: 0.5)
    var counter = 0.0
    let duration = colorize.duration

    for row in blocks {
      for sprite in row {
        counter++

        let duration = counter * duration
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(duration)

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, colorize]))
      }
    }
  }

  func getLabel(withText text:String) -> SKLabelNode {
    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")
    label.fontColor = .whiteColor()
    label.text = text
    label.fontSize = 20
    label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
    label.verticalAlignmentMode = .Center

    return label
  }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

So basically, as I said in the comments, you can run all the actions at the same moment, it is just about when the each action will start.

Comment: How can I do if the animation is above other node that is not the principal?

Comment: Sorry sometime its difficult to explain, I will trying again. I have a { let tileLayer = SKNode() } Its in that node where is added the boxes. I mean, when I add something to the scene instead doing {addchild(square)} I do {tileLayer.addchild(square)}. So when I´m changing the color the action doesn't work :(

Comment: @AnaMM As I said, you have to run colorizing action on each square , not on a scene or on the tileLayer node.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to imagine that `runAction(waiting)` means that you *code* pauses and waits, pausing between loops. It doesn't (and in fact there is no way to do that). Your code loops through all the loops, *now*, *KABOOM*, immediately.

Thus, all the actions are configured immediately and are performed together.